# Javascript create array with fixed value but matching column amount from another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array which is built from data dynamically, so it can change.

It's basically this:

```
["t1", "something", "bird", "dog", "cow", "fish"]
```

What I need to do is to count how many of them there are and create another array with the same amount of columns but all with the value of 1.

For example, if the array is:

```
["bird", "dog", "cow", "fish"]
```

then it creates an array of:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1]
```

If the array is:

```
["bird", "fish"]
```

then it creates an array of:

```
[1, 1]
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a new array of equal length and use the fill function.

```
var myArray = ["dog","cat","monkey"];

var secondArray = new Array(myArray.length).fill(1);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method:

```
var input = ["foo", "bar", "baz"];
var mapped = input.map(function () { return 1; });
```

Comment: There's an extra } on the right. Apart from that I tried console.log(mapped); but got nothing

Comment: Why does it say Undefined?

Answer (score 0):

```
// es6
var array = ["t1", "something", "bird", "dog", "cow", "fish"]
array.map(() =>  1); // => [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

// if you don't care if they are strings 
'1'.repeat(array.length).split(''); //=> ["1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1"]
```